# Kentico search by classnames

Tags: kentico

I have a problem with with filtering my search results by ClassNames. Below you can find a code snippet that I use, hope somebody has an idea and can help me.

```
SearchParameters parameters = new SearchParameters()
        {
            SearchFor = "support",
            SearchSort = "##SCORE##",
            Path = "/%",
            ClassNames = "cms.faq",                
            CurrentCulture = "EN-US",
            DefaultCulture = CMS.Helpers.CultureHelper.EnglishCulture.IetfLanguageTag,
            CombineWithDefaultCulture = false,
            CheckPermissions = false,
            SearchInAttachments = false,
            User = (CMS.Membership.UserInfo)CMS.Membership.MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser,
            SearchIndexes = index.IndexName,
            StartingPosition = 0,
            DisplayResults = 10,
            NumberOfProcessedResults = 10,
            NumberOfResults = 0,
            AttachmentWhere = String.Empty,
            AttachmentOrderBy = String.Empty
        };
```

I could not find any documentation on this, but I suppose the class name should return only data of the type FAQ, but in my case it returns other data to like files, news and custom documents.

I tried also to add something like ClassNames = "+cms.faq" or ClassNames = "##cms.faq##" but had no luck with that :D

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classnames parameter is obsolete and it should not be used anymore. The parameter is still there because of backward compatibility, it was used to filter out search attachments when using SQL search as rocky already mentioned. If you want to filter search results by ClassNames you have to specify the classname righ in **SearchFor** property like this: `+(apple) +classname:[cms.faq TO cms.faq] +_culture:([en-us TO en-us]`

Answer (score 1):

I just quickly went through the source code of v8.2 and it seems that the `ClassNames` parameter is only used to filter out searched attachments. I'm not sure if this is intentional or if it's a bug. I recommend you to contact [Kentico support](http://www.kentico.com/Support/Submit-support-issue).

The correct format of the `ClassNames` is a semicolon separated list of page types e.g. `CMS.Faq;CMS.News`.